# "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." Django-rest-frameweork and React

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm trying to create `Club` object via React form but I get those 2 errors:
`{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}` and `401 Unauthorized`. Obviously there is something wrong with authorisation, I tested it with postman and it did not work, however when I tried with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/clubs/` everything worked. I am pasting all of my code below.

frontend/CreateClub.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Base from '../base/Base';
import { isAuthenticated } from '../user/helper/userApiCalls';
import { getAllClubs, createClub } from './helper/apiHelper';

const CreateClub = () => {
    const [clubName, setClubName] = useState('');
    const [clubs, setClubs] = useState([]);
    const [nameTaken, setNameTaken] = useState(false);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() =>{
        if (!isAuthenticated()) {
            navigate('/login')
        } else {
            loadClubs();
        }
    },[])

    const loadClubs = () => {
        getAllClubs()
        .then((data) => {
            setClubs(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setClubName(event.target.value)
    }

    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (checkExistingClubNames(clubName, clubs)) {
            const owner = isAuthenticated().user;
            const name = clubName;
            createClub({owner, name})
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.name === clubName) {
                    setClubName('');
                    setNameTaken(false);
                    navigate('/');
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        } else {
            setNameTaken(true);
        }
    }

    const checkExistingClubNames = (newClubsName, existingClubs) => {
        const filteredClubs = existingClubs.filter(function(existingClub) {
            return existingClub.name === newClubsName
        })
        if (filteredClubs.length > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        };
    };

    const createClubForm = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Create Club:</h2><hr/>
                <form>
                    <div>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input
                        name="clubName"
                        value={clubName}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        type="name"
                    />
                    </div>
                    <button
                    onClick={onSubmit}
                    >
                    Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return ( 
        <Base title="Create Club">
            {loading && <h1>Loading...</h1>}
            {!loading && createClubForm()}
            {nameTaken && <p>Name taken</p>}
        </Base>
    );
}

export default CreateClub;
```

apiHelper.js

```
export const getAllClubs = () => {
    return (
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/clubs/', {method:"GET"})
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    )
};

export const createClub = (club) => {
    return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/clubs/', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(club),
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

frontend/userApiCalls.js

```
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
    if (typeof window == undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("jwt")) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'))
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

game/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

backend/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Club

class ClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = 'id', 'owner', 'name'
```

backend/views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Club
from .serializers import ClubSerializer

class ClubViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer
```

backend/game/urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import GameViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clubs', ClubViewSet, basename="clubs")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

backend/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include("game.urls")),
    path('api/accounts/', include("accounts.urls")),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

There's a lot of code, but to be honest I have no idea what to do next and I hope you can help me :/

Comment: Try to add to your POST request header `"Authorization": "Bearer your-jwt-token"`

Comment: @SergeyPugach I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

if in your settings.py file you have the following syntax remove them help me to work fine

```
'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'AUTHORIZATION',
```